# Modify document root in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am more used to create virtaul hosts than using htaccess but I have to do it so:

My projectX is on wamp server. Normally I can reach the application with url:

```
http://localhost/projectX/web/app_dev.php
```

I would like to reach the site, that way :

```
http://projectX.mydomain.fr/app_dev.php
```

I guess I should change the htaccess in the web folder but how ? Can somebody help ?

ty.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your domain in your Windows host file:

```
# add this line to : C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

127.0.0.1    projectX.mydomain.fr
```

Then you need to declare the new virtual host in wamp:

```
# add this lines to : C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName projectX.mydomain.fr
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/projectX/web"
    ServerAdmin admin@dev.mydomain.fr

    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/projectX/web/">
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn


    # put an existing log directory here or wamp will not start
    ErrorLog "c:/wamp/www/projectX/logs/projectX-error.log"
    CustomLog "c:/wamp/www/projectX/logs/projectX-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart your Wamp server and it should work.

---

**EDIT:** If you're only concerned about rewriting the base path, here is a simple `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/projectX/web/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projectX/web/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is this the answer ? I know how to create virtual host... the question concerns htaccess.

Comment: can you delete your answer pls?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please be more specific when you ask a question as this one is quite unclear.

Comment: I have this error using your solution :Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the rewriteCond to prevent redirection loop